# Can I get phonegap build ios to target the device instead of the emulator?

Tags: cordova

It seems like phonegap wants to target the iphone simulator when I do a build. How can I target the device?

```
kit:fx-client kitsunde$ phonegap build ios
[phonegap] detecting iOS SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] compiling iOS...
Build settings from command line:
    ARCHS = i386
    CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = /Users/kitsunde/Development/fx-client/src/fx-client/platforms/ios/build/emulator
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator7.1
    VALID_ARCHS = i386
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding --device after "phonegap local run ios". Ie,

```
phonegap local run ios --device
```

Comment: That seems to work with `run` but not with `build`. I'm trying to automate the build process by making `ipa`'s, but run drops me into `lldb`.

Comment: Sorry - what? It works but doesn't? :) Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Ela, your comment has nothing to do with this particular post.